# Docusign Connect: Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, docusignapi

After 4 years of reliable operation, my PHP listener script started to fail from October 8th, 2019 onwards with the

> Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have not changed anything on my server. The SSL certificate is a valid v3 from Lets Encrypt. TLS is 1.2.

I have been on support calls for hours with no resolution, other than them telling me that I need to install their certificates here: https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates

The problem is that I don't know how I would integrate that with my server, and my web host doesn't know either. When asked, they are not able to explain it either.

The listener script on my server is fairly simple:

```
function guid() {
    $uuid = '';
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        $uuid = com_create_guid();
        // somehow the function com_create_guid includes {}, while our webservice
        // doesn't. Here we are changing the format by taking those curly braces out.
        $uuid = str_ireplace("{", "", $uuid );
        $uuid = str_ireplace("}", "", $uuid );
    } else {
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
        .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,20,12);
    }
    return $uuid;
}

// Figure out the URL of this server
// NOTE: DocuSign only pushes status to HTTPS!
$postBackPath = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$postBackPath .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$postedXml = @file_get_contents('php://input');

if (!empty($_POST['post'])) {
    // if this is a sample load
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("post.sample") or die("Unable to load sample XML file!");
    $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID = guid(); // here we replace the GUID so we have unique files

    // using the curl library to get the post
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,30); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $postBackPath);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec ( $curl );
    curl_close ($curl);
} 
else if(!empty($postedXml)) {
    // see if this is a post to this page if it is then we have to save it.
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($postedXml);
    $post = $xml;
    print 'Got Envelope ID: ' . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . '<br />';
}
```

After that code, it just parses data from the xml that I pass into my CRM.

On the Docusign Connect setup, I have the log enabled and require acknowledgement. All of the integration and security settings are unchecked (HMAC signature, Include basic authentication header, require mutual TLS, use SOAP interface, enable mutual TLS are all unchecked).

**UPDATE:** A response from my webhost assisting in this issue:

> Hello again.
>
> I took a look at the SSL you presently have installed for
>   sub.domain.com (you can see the info from Chrome browser) If you
>   click on the lock in the url bar and then click on Certificate >
>   Details > Version you (or docusign) can see that that cert is version
>   3 as they specified that you need.
>
> I'm not clear on where they think that you should install their
>   certificate though.  The cert at the link provided is to cover
>   na2.docusign.net which is not hosted on your server so there's no
>   place to install that that I'm aware of. You can verify that by
>   downloading the NA2 certificate from the link they provided:
>   https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates
>
> Open the .cer file in the simplest text editor you have available and
>   paste the contents in here:
>   https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html
>
> That will give you all the information about the certificate.  Under
>   "Subject:" you'll see CN = na2.docusign.net which means that it covers
>   their domain not yours.
>
> I'm afraid we'll need more information from DocuSign to be able to
>   assist you.  If this SSL were installed on your domain, it would fail
>   authenticity checks run by any browser connecting to your site which
>   isn't going to instill any confidence for your visitors.

This was my impression as well, so I feel like we are misunderstanding how this certificate from Docusign would work in conjunction with the certificate we already have from Lets Encrypt.

**Is this a coding issue?**

I am using a very simple Docusign connect integration, which is just a php listener catching the XML from a completed envelope and parsing it so I can pass that to my CRM.

Comment: you might need to install the DocuSign certificate on your server. It probably was updated and the old one expire

Comment: This is the part we are confused on. We never installed a Docusign certificate to begin with, and wouldn't know how to either. Docusign doesn't provide any instructions on how to do so, and my webhost is unsure how to install an SSL certificate signed by another domain to replace our current one.

Comment: there are no instructions because it depends on your server architecture etc. This is an IT task, usually these things are done by IT networking professionals who install many certificates

Comment: As I said, my web host doesn't understand this either (Liquid Web). We are on a Linus OS on a cPanel v84.0.4 CENTOS7.6. Is there no documentation or step-by-step procedure on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I found this - https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-a-ssl-certificate-on-a-domain-using-cpanel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this article: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/mutual-tls-apache2 and pass this to my server administrator. This was apparently had the missing info they needed to get it working. Not really an answer, but if you are struggling like I was, this will help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. after 5 hours digging into the internet, Here my change which resolved my issue:

+=+ all the update is related to the Haproxy certification setting, I added these three lines to the haproxy.conf file:

```
tune.ssl.default-dh-param  2048

ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
```

Answer (score -1):

see information on this page:
https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates

"The renewed Connect certificates listed below are slated to be introduced into the DocuSign Service in the September 2019 - November 2019 timeframe. The ‘offer’ date specified below is the date the renewed certificate will be available for consumption and the ‘enforce’ date is when the renewed certificate will be the only option i.e. the current certificate will no longer be available for consumption."

You would have to update the certificate from that page on your server to fix this.

Comment: Ok, that is what they say, but neither myself nor my webhost understands what that entails. I have an SSL certificate (via Lets Encrypt) on my server already. So where,how would I install this certificate?

Comment: You need to install it in your Root , where you install all other certificates.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I have only installed SSL certificates using a cPanel interface. Is there any documentation out there for how to do this outside of that?

Comment: try this - https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-a-ssl-certificate-on-a-domain-using-cpanel/

Comment: So I can have multiple SSL certificates on one domain? And ones that point to different domains than the domain they reside on?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on in this topic.